# filtering data view results and binding values to a grid which has paging

Tags: c#

I have a grid view which has paging. After binding the data to the grid view I am filtering the grid based on selection of dropdown. which is resulting the results in 2 pages. But when I clicked on 2nd page the grid is refreshing with original results. Here is my code:

```
DataTable dtSyncQueueTransfer = syncStatusBizManager.GetSyncTransferResult(syncRequestId, serverIds, statusIds, txtFileName.Value);
ViewState["SyncResults"] = dtSyncQueueTransfer;
gvSyncQueueList.DataSource = dtSyncQueueTransfer;
gvSyncQueueList.DataBind();

protected void ddlProjectId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtSyncResults = (DataTable)ViewState["SyncResults"];
    //To display all the sync results when the dropdown selected value is All.
    if (ddlProjectId.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("All"))
    {
        gvSyncQueueList.DataSource = dtSyncResults;
        gvSyncQueueList.DataBind();
    }
    //To display the sync results when the user selects a projectId from the drop down.
    else
    {
        DataView viewResults = new DataView(dtSyncResults);
        //Filtering sync results based on projectid.
        viewResults.RowFilter = "ProjectId =" + Convert.ToInt32(ddlProjectId.SelectedValue);
        gvSyncQueueList.DataSource = viewResults;
        gvSyncQueueList.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvSyncQueueList_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvSyncQueueList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvSyncQueueList.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["SyncResults"];
    gvSyncQueueList.DataBind();
    string activetab = GetActiveTab();
    ShowTabs(activetab);
}
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: That code won't compile because of the first four lines. Where is that code actually located?

Comment: that code located on some buttton click where I need to display the grid with actual results instead of filtering. After that I am filtering the grid based on selection of dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for my question. we need to re-filter the results on paging.
On change of grid page we need to change the code as follows:

```
protected void gvSyncQueueList_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvSyncQueueList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    //To view all the sync results when the page first time loads or when the drop down value is all.
    if (ddlProjectId.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("All") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlProjectId.SelectedValue.ToString()))
        gvSyncQueueList.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["SyncResults"];
    //To bind the project results according to drop down value selected in paging.
    else
    {
        DataView viewResults = new DataView((DataTable)ViewState["SyncResults"]);
        viewResults.RowFilter = "ProjectId =" + Convert.ToInt32(ddlProjectId.SelectedValue);
        gvSyncQueueList.DataSource = viewResults;
    }
    gvSyncQueueList.DataBind();
    string activetab = GetActiveTab();
    ShowTabs(activetab);
}
```